# Adding Search feature in Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, full-text-search, search-engine, thinking-sphinx

I have developed a database backed application in Rails 3 www.pajamadeals.in . Now, I intend to include search feature in it. Where people can search books, instruments, etc. How do I implement search feature. Any gem or plugin recommendation? Should I roll my own code for search capability?

Answer (score 5):

There are couple of gem is usefull for full text searching

1) You can use [thinking-sphinix](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/),for quick start up you can refer http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx,

2) You can use [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) you can refer http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot

3) [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/appendix/clients.html)

Sphinix is a good solution fr easy start.